# Nasm. Reading and printing an interger using scanf and printf

Tags: assembly, io, x86, nasm

The following is the code i wrote for reading and printing an interger using scanf and printf. However the printresults are incorrect.

```
Section .data

formatint: db "%d",0
formatintout: db "%d",10,0

section .bss

i: resd 1
j: resd 1
n: resd 1

section .text
extern printf
extern scanf
global main

main:

push n
push formatint
call scanf
add esp,8 

push n
push formatintout
call printf
add esp,6

exit:
mov eax,1
mov ebx,0
int 80h
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that for `scanf` you need to pass the address, but for `printf` you need to pass the value. You are passing the address in both cases. You should do `push dword [n]` for the `printf`.

`add esp, 6` should of course be `add esp, 8`. I assume that's just a typo.

Also note that it is not recommended to use the exit syscall. You should just `ret` from `main`, or use `call exit` if you really want to.